# Move mouse cursor on the page

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to automate the password generation process where I have to move the mouse cursor on the page and the scale is growing. Is it possible to do so with JS?

[image]

I was trying to do so with Cypress in different ways but it didn't work.

```
cy.get('.form')
            .trigger('mouseover')
            .trigger('mousedown')
            .trigger('mousemove',  200, 100)
            .trigger('mousemove',  300, 450)
            .trigger('mousemove',  200, 100)
```

Comment: can you share your html as well ?

Comment: "it didn't work" is a useless problem description. Can you try and be more specific?

Comment: @ChrisG the mouse cursor doesn't move and grade doesn't grow accordingly.

Comment: The reason you’re asked to move your mouse cursor, is to create a “better” randomness, if you replace that by mouse movements that are “random” by using the computers random number generator, then you are decreasing the effectivity of this measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mousemove event is probably not attached to the form, possibly the document

```
cy.document().trigger('mousemove',  200, 100)
```

If not, open up devtools, inspect the scale and look at Elements tab, RH pane / Event Listeners. Click Ancestors, look for the mousemove event and see where it's attached.